# how to change display in ubuntu server

Tags: linux, server

i have this problem to read what i'm typing on my linux server because everything is so small is there by any chance you can customize your display settings on linux server my screen resolution is 3200x1800 [problem][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKwaM.jpg**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

you have to install vmware tools and then you are able to maximize or go to full screen
check this 
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525